# Valor condicional en autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tengo una forma en react que utilizo para agregar y editar los datos, utilizo un autocomplete para más comodidad cuando agrego un nuevo registro no tengo problemas, pero al momento de querer editarlo no me muestra el valor en el cuadro de texto aparece este en blanco pero si le hago click en guardar si lo guarda.

Lo que estoy intentando con el siguiente codigo es que si en los props el id es 0 es decir que es un nuevo registro tome el valor  del autocomplete y si no que tome el valor que traigo en los props, pero me sigue apareciendo en blanco el cuadro de texto,¿Cual podria ser el problema?

```
   const [datos, setDatos] = useState({id: 0, nombre: "", apellido: "", fecha: "",tipo:0,tipos:null});

   const[list, setList]=useState({Lista:[]});
   
   const [dataAutoComplete, setDataAutoComplete] = useState({  TipoAuto: null });  

   const defaultProps={
      options:list.Lista,
      getOptionLabel: option => option.tipos
   };

   const handleChangeAutoTipo=(event)=>{
      if(props.elregistro.id===0)
      {
      setDataAutoComplete({...dataAutoComplete,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
      setDatos({...datos,tipo:event.target.value.tipoid})
      }  

      if(props.elregistro.id>0)
      {
         setDataAutoComplete({...dataAutoComplete, TipoAuto:props.elregistro.tipos})
         setDatos({...datos,tipo:props.elregistro.tipos.tipoid)

       }

           <Autocomplete}
              {...defaultProps}
                 id="TipoAuto"
                 autoComplete              
                 includeInputInList
                 value={dataAutoComplete.TipoAuto}
                 onChange={(event, newVal)=>handleChangeAutoTipo({target:{name:"TipoAuto",value: newVal
                 }
                 })}
                 renderInput={params => (
                 <TextField {...params}   label="Tipos"  margin="normal" variant="outlined" fullWidth="true" />
              )}
           />
```

Ejemplo de los props

```
   elregistro{
    id:4,
    nombre:"pedro"
    apellido:"ramirez"
    fecha:"2020-12-04"
    tipo: 6
    tipos:{tipoid:1, tipo:"comun"}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El que estés utilizando dos objetos dentro de tu state como lo son "dataAutoComplete" y "datos" es un poco confuso y puede complicarte la vida, como es el caso, te recomendaría que solamente uses un objeto para tener el state de tu componente, para este ejemplo mantendremos el objeto "datos" y a partir de ahí tomaremos el valor para tu Autocomplete, a su vez te recomiendo que tu state de "datos" lo tomes a partir de tu parámetro "elregistro", si tu registro no se ha creado podemos inicializarlo con ciertos atributos por default.
Para identificar que elemento está seleccionado dentro de tu autocomplete puedes usar el atributo llamado getOptionSelected.
Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
const CustomAutocomplete = (props = {}) => {
  const {
    elregistro = {
      id: 0,
      nombre: "",
      apellido: "",
      fecha: "",
      tipo: 0,
      tipos: null,
    },
  } = props;
  const [datos, setDatos] = React.useState(elregistro);

  const [list, setList] = React.useState([
    { tipoid: 1, tipo: "Común" },
    { tipoid: 2, tipo: "Poco común" },
    { tipoid: 3, tipo: "Raro" },
  ]);

  const defaultProps = {
    options: list,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.tipo,
  };

  const handleChangeAutoTipo = (event) => {
    setDatos((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      tipo: event.target.value ? event.target.value.tipoid : 0,
      tipos: event.target.value,
    }));
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...defaultProps}
      id="TipoAuto"
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      value={datos.tipos}
      onChange={(event, newVal) =>
        handleChangeAutoTipo({ target: { name: "TipoAuto", value: newVal } })
      }
      getOptionSelected={(option = {}, selection = {}) =>
        option.tipoid === selection.tipoid
      }
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Tipos"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth={true}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Si los tiene es la parte de aqui  {...defaultProps} , el problema no es que no aparezcan las opciones al agregar un nuevo registro, el problema es cuando voy a editar un registro existente  se queda en blanco no me aprece el valor que habia puesto a ese registro

Comment: Podrías compartirnos el código completo del componente ? En especial la función handleChangeAutoTipo, puede ser que la estructura del objeto que guardas es distinta al listado de options del elemento, de igual forma podrías validar si te está arrojando este error en consola? Por lo general debería arrojarte que no hizo un Match correcto.

Comment: Ya edite la publicación agregue el código del autocomplete y puse un ejemplo para que se comprenda mejor el problema

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya se queda el valor en el cuadro de texto y guarda los datos correctamente, una pregunta cuando limpio el autocomplete la pagina se pone en blanco y sale un error Exception error pause tipoid is null, que puede estar sucediendo?, si se supone que el valor esta controlado

Comment: Puedes probar modificando esta linea en tu callback para cambiar el tipo:  tipo: event.target.value ? event.target.value.tipoid : 0, básicamente el error es porque cuando limpias el autocomplete en tu evento onChange tu segundo parámetro de callback es igual a null, entonces cuando intentas ingresar a una propiedad de un null falla.